# Indexing all diagonals of a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I am trying to index (not get) the diagonals of a matrix in matlab.

Say I have a matrix "M", that is n by n. Then I want to obtain all indeces of all possible diagonals in the matrix "M".

I know that the center diagonal is indexed by

```
M(1:(n+1):end)
```

and all the following diagonals above it are indexed as:

```
M((1+1*n):(n+1):end)
M((1+2*n):(n+1):end)...
M((1+n*n):(n+1):end)
```

Now I also want to get the diagonals below. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to however.

Reproducible example:

```
rng(1); % set seed
n = 4;
M = rand(n);
```

yielding

```
M =

   0.562408   0.947364   0.655088   0.181702
   0.960604   0.268834   0.469042   0.089167
   0.578719   0.657845   0.516215   0.419000
   0.226410   0.601666   0.169212   0.378740
```

where I would like to index the lower diagonals, e.g. the subdiagonal:

```
0.960604 0.657845 0.169212
```

That is, I don't need to get the diagonal by e.g. the diags function, but access the index (since I ultimately want to replace the matrix entries diagonal by diagonal).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you already noted, you can use the [`diag`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diag.html) function to get the main diagonal and other diagonals above or below the main diagonals,

```
M = magic(4)    % Test data
M =
    16     2     3    13
     5    11    10     8
     9     7     6    12
     4    14    15     1

diag(M, -1)
ans =
     5
     7
    15
```

but you can not assign values to the diagonal with the `diag` function:

```
diag(M, -1) = [3; 2; 1]
Index in position 2 is invalid. Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.
```

Instead, we can use [logical indexing](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html#MatrixIndexingExample-3) by indexing the array `M` with a logical matrix of the same size. We can easily create this matrix using the `diag` function, by creating a diagonal matrix with ones on the specified diagonal:

```
diag(ones(1, 3), -1)
ans =
     0     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0
     0     0     1     0
```

To use this matrix for logical indexing, we need to convert it from double to logical with the [`logical`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logical.html) function.

```
M(logical(diag(ones(1, 3), -1)))
ans =
     5
     7
    15
```

or assign new values to it with

```
M(logical(diag(ones(1, 3), -1))) = [99, 98, 97]
M =
    16     2     3    13
    99    11    10     8
     9    98     6    12
     4    14    97     1
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a slightly more performant way of using `diag` to get indices to a diagonal:

```matlab
n = 5;                  % matrix size
M = reshape(1:n*n,n,n); % matrix with linear indices
indices = diag(M, ii);  % indices to diagonal ii
```

However, it is much easier to just compute the right indices directly. As discovered by OP, the upper diagonal elements are given by:

```matlab
indices = (1+ii*n):(n+1):(n*n);
```

(Note that the parenthesis are not necessary, as the colon operator has the lowest precedence.)

The lower diagonal elements are given by:

```matlab
indices = (1+ii):(n+1):((n-ii)*n);
```

Both series are identical for the main diagonal, where `ii=0`.

We can verify correctness of these calculations by using the first method:

```matlab
n = 5;                  % matrix size
M = reshape(1:n*n,n,n); % matrix with linear indices
for ii=1:n-1
   indices = (1+ii*n):(n+1):(n*n);
   assert(isequal(indices, diag(M, ii).'))
   indices = (1+ii):(n+1):((n-ii)*n);
   assert(isequal(indices, diag(M, -ii).'))
end
```